# Send email from template (.oft file) - Exchange Service using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

I would like to send back confirmation mails to all incoming mails. Therefore I have a .oft file, which should serve as template and the code will then insert the date value via a certain keyword.
This is how I send an email normally:

```
var email = new EmailMessage(exchangeService);
email.ToRecipients.AddRange(recipients);
email.SendAndSaveCopy(sentItemsFolderId);
```

Is it possible to load an email template (.oft) and then send this?
It would be nice not having to create the whole email body in code...

I have connected to the Exchange Service 2013.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load an oft in EWS, you could import a Mime (EML file) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-import-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange in to the drafts folder then make changes to it and then send that. Or you could just skip and use another library like mimekit to build the Message as a Mime message and then send that via EWS